# place SVG over html elements

Tags: html, svg

I am using SVG for some chart. But i have problem with svg popup window. As you can see on the picture html div(green bar) overlaps black popup. Is there any way to place svg over html elements(over green bar in my case )?

---

in ie9 same page is ok.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This does not answer the question, but is worth pointing out.  With modern css techniques, like rounded corners, gradients and icon fonts you could replicate the (second) above graphic in (fairly semantic) html alone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is certainly possible to place SVG over HTML elements ([see this example](http://jsfiddle.net/cs5eJ/)).

I'm afraid I can't see your image due to firewall :(

Comment: worth noting that only need to use the floatTL class, from the referenced fiddle/example, on the div containing the svg element

Answer (score 9):

The issue here doesn't just apply to SVGs. It's to do with element positioning. Any positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative) are displayed in front of any non-positioned elements.

```css
.box{ width: 200px; height: 200px; }

.blue{
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  
}
.red{
  background-color: red;
  //position: relative; /*see what happens when you remove this*/
}
```

```html
<div class="box blue">
</div>

<div class="box red">
</div>
```

Comment: I had the same issue. The SVG did not have any position set but the background had position: abosolute. Settings SVG to position: absolute did the trick. Thanks. I thought that it has to be something with the SVG element, but it's a basic positioning thing :)