# d3 svg elements on top of background color (but not content) of separate HTML element

Tags: d3.js, svg, geojson

OK, this is a weird one. I have two divs inside a container div:

```
<div class="ri-full-width-container">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div class="ri-limited-width-container">
</div>
```

D3 is creating a GeoJSON map in the #map div. The other div sits on top of that background map. What's odd is that that overlay div's content (text and buttons) appear over the map, as expected. BUT the background color of the overlay is visible, but it's BEHIND the svg elements of the map.

I know that SVG renders based on when it's added to the DOM, but since they're in a div that appears earlier in the DOM and, more importantly, the rest of that overlay div is on top of the SVG just fine, can anyone explain why the background color is behind the svg elements?

Live code:
https://beehivemedia.com/dataviz/map_oddity/test_file.html

Screenshot of what I'm talking about:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a css issue,

from an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609114/place-svg-over-html-elements):

> The issue here doesn't just apply to SVGs. It's to do with element positioning. Any positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative) are displayed in front of any non-positioned elements.

Your `.ri-limited-width-container` has no positioning, so its background appears behind the positioned `#map` div while its child `.ri-menu` is positioned so it appears as intended.

Changing the `.ri-limited-width-container` positioning to relative should get you something like:

[image]

Comment: Wow - I never would have guessed that one. You just saved me a lot of heartache! Thank you!